# Extension to Save Credit Card Details to Create One Step Checkout Process

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

We are into Magento ecommerce development and we would like to know if there is any possibility to save credit card details of the user (name, CC number, Exp Date).  We are creating one website with a fast checkout process, so whenever a repeat customer wants to purchase something he/she does not have to see or update billing, shipping and payment information. Let us know, if there are any Magento extensions, any audio, video tutorials or any documentation that could help us to achieve our aim.

I tried with CLS PayPal Credit Card Tokenization, but failed to get expected results, we will be glad if we get any hints, guidance or help.

Thanks a lot in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Even though the questions seems a bit to broad and could be answered with various payment methods which support this, I'm trying to give a little bit of information here:

What you are looking for is called **Alias function**. A function where the payment data is stored in the payment system and a token is saved in your Magento shop which can be selected by your customer next time they go through the checkout.

I don't want to do advertisement here but I know that some of the Customweb extensions support this alias function, see [here](https://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/eur/extensions/module/unterstuetzte-shopsysteme/magento.html).

Comment: I've never heard it called 'alias function'... the generic term is tokenization, and that's exactly what the CLS PayPal module referenced does. There are a bunch of other extensions available for all sorts of gateways (Authorize.Net CIM, First Data, Braintree, ...). -but that doesn't really solve the question, which is looking for a solution that will do that and replace the *entire* checkout.